# Can collins parser give me the dependency relations?

Tags: parsing, dependencies, nlp, parse-tree

I would like to obtain dependency tree by [Collins parser](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/code.html). I am wondering if such a thing exist.

I know that there are many other parsers which can provide me the dependency tree, but I am using a dataset which uses collins parser to parse the text. So, I would like to get the dependency tree by the same parser.

But, unfortunately, I can't see anything about how to get dependency relations in Collins parser's readme file.

I would be thankful if anybody helps me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Collin's parser is a constituency one, and therefore does not directly provide dependency trees. You have two options:

- convert constituency to dependency parse: https://code.google.com/p/clearnlp/wiki/C2DConvert
- use one of the many available dependency parsers